# C extern struct without header?

Tags: c, struct, extern

I want to extern a function that has `struct` as a parameter, but I do not have access to source code of the file containing function and struct definition. I cannot create a header and put the `struct` in there as I don't know the fields of the struct.

How to extern `struct` without header?

Comment: How can you call the function without knowing about the struct?

Comment: Is the function taking a `struct`, or a *pointer* to a `struct`?

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev the function takes _pointer_ to a `struct`

Comment: @Nithi89: Then you can simply go on with a forward declaration of the struct: `struct foo; void func(struct foo *);`

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: What if the structure is passed by value? How to handle the situation?

Comment: Confident that if the `struct` is passed by value then you need access to the structure definition first.  Short of making a fake, but same size structure, I think you are out of luck.

Comment: If I define the `struct` again locally, when the function is called will it still get the values passed to it, or will it take the local values from the definition?